# Apple Mac Ventura Time Machine always want to erase the content of my external drive - how to kep data & time machine backup?

Tags: macos-ventura, timemachine

I bought a new Mac Air M1 and I can not find out how to stop Time Machine to erase the content of my external drive.

I tried formatting the "container" as the old HFS+ format as explained in [Steve Sande's post](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/62926-reverting-an-apfs-drive-to-hfs-the-easy-way/) BUT it does not work.

```
 format drive as APFS in Disk Utility
 then select "container" & reformat as MacOS Extended Journaled (HFS+)
 copy some files onto the external usb drive 2TB
 ask TM to backup... it wants to erase the content of the drive.
```

I have always used TM to share external drive with other data... how can I do the same on Ventura?

Comment: You want time machine data, AND additional extra data? I've created a .DMG file and then used that for my backup drive. That had a couple advantages, but it was a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @matt I used to do that.  In fact on my MBP on Ventura that is what I do for TM BU but when I try to format a new drive for my wife MBA also on Ventura it does not work.  What about creating 2 partitions?

Comment: Try asking on SuperUser site

Comment: @RohitGupta please send link to that forum/site.